# iptables/pf rule to only allow XY application/user?

Tags: iptables, firewall, pf

I think there is no iptables/pf solution to only allow an XY application on e.g.: outbound tcp port 80, eth0. So if I have a userid: "500" then how could I block any other communications then the mentioned on port 80/outbound/tcp/eth0? (e.g.: just privoxy is using port 80 on eth0)

Extra: virtualbox uses port 80 too? when a browser on the guest os visits a site..how to declaire that? - setting the normal user would be too much hole

Comment: admittedly it might be easier if you split this question into 2 (or more) questions... the bsd stuff is going to be way different from the linux stuff... and then in many ways you also have a virtual box question. I personally think that "how do I only allow application/user XY through iptables" and "how do I only allow application/user XY through pf" are good questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

here's the `iptables` command to allow for a certain `uid` through a certain port.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m owner --uid-owner username -j ACCEPT
```

from the man page

> [!] --uid-owner userid[-userid]
>               Matches  if  the packet socket’s file structure (if it has one) is owned by the given user. You may also specify a numerical UID, or an UID range.

as far as virtualbox.. I believe it runs its own kernel... so you might want to use the `--uid-owner` of virtualbox on the host OS, but then have a `--uid-owner` owner rule on the virtual machine as well.

It might also be useful to note that `--gid-owner` also exists, and you could create a group `browser` and `sgid` your browser apps so it runs with an effective group `browser` and then only put users who you want to have browsing in that group... this would not be a perfect solution... but most of the users wouldn't try to run any other apps as that group, thus generally restricting the outbound to that application I believe. I haven't tried this, so I'm not 100% that it would work as I've described.